# jQuery hover - perform next transition only after current is over

Tags: jquery, timeout, hover

How do I time my transitions out, so the next one will only start when the current one's finished? The way it is now it jumps to the next transition while in the middle of the current, and it looks jumpy, especially when I hover over a bunch of links quickly.

Here's a link to how it looks like http://dynamo.kco.ie/about-us/clients , and my code is:

```
function slideShow() { 
    $("#list .client").unbind('mouseover');
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('rel');
    var image1 = $("#clientImage1");
    var image2 = $("#clientImage2");

  if(image1.is(":visible")){
      image2.attr('src', imgSrc); 
      image2.stop(true, true).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 400, function() {
         $("#list .client").mouseover(slideShow);
      });  
              image1.stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 400);
              //image1.hide();
      }
      else{
          image1.attr('src', imgSrc);
          image1.stop(true, true).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 400);
          image2.stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 400);
    }

    // binding  
    $("#list .client").mouseover(slideShow);
}


$("#list .client").mouseover(function(){
   slideShow();
});
```

### Any ideas?

Edit:

Thanks so much for your help, finally got it to work with hoverIntent! The working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#clientImage2").hide();  
    $("#list .client").hoverIntent(config); 

});


var config = {    
     over: slideShow, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
     timeout: 600, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
     out: doNothing // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
};
function slideShow() {
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('rel');
    var image1 = $("#clientImage1");
    var image2 = $("#clientImage2");

    if(image1.is(":visible")){
      image2.attr('src', imgSrc); 
      image2.stop(true, true).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 600);  
      image1.stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 600);
      }
    else{
      image1.attr('src', imgSrc);
      image1.stop(true, true).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 600);
      image2.stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 600);
      }
}

function doNothing(){}
```

Comment: With http://api.jquery.com/queue/  probably. But can I ask you something? I intentionally didn't see your question to check whether I can find the problem in your page but the main problem in my opinion is that the second image when it is loading, it also loads the same image in the first part of the slideshow which is kinda ugly.

Comment: It takes too long to finish, nobody is going to wait for it. Maybe changing the event to click instead of mouseover, and making it go fast will help.

Comment: @ramono It was 2000 just for testing, it's gonna be 400 or 600 once it works...To make it faster doesn't help. The problem is not the speed but the fact that it stops in mid-transition to do the next one instead of finishing what it started first.

Comment: What i meant is, if i hover over 8 of them in one move, i will still have to wait 400x8.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `stop()`'s from

`stop(true,true)` to `stop(true,false)`